# KeyError when uploading files to Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

Documentation: https://flask-ptbr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/patterns/fileuploads.html

I was following the documentation above to save photo uploads from my flask app; however, I am getting a KeyError on the UPLOAD_FOLDER.

I saved the UPLOAD_FOLDER path in the flask.cfg file within the instance folder:

```
# flask.cfg
TOP_LEVEL_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = TOP_LEVEL_DIR + '/project/static/img/'
```

here is the route.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from project.models import Plants
from .forms import AddPlantForm, EditPlantForm
from project import db, app
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@plants_blueprint.route('/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_plant():
    form = AddPlantForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if 'plant_photo' not in request.files:
                flash('No plant photo added')
                return redirect(request.url)

            file = request.files['plant_photo']

            if file.filename=='':
                flash('No plant photo selected ')
                return redirect(request.url)


            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                url = os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_URL'], filename)
            else:
                filename = ''
                url = ''
```

KeyError on line below

```
#KeyError: 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: How are you loading your flask.cfg file?

Comment: within my __init__.py: app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')

Comment: In `project/__init__.py`?

Comment: yes in project/__init__.py